# Excerpt - add the last few words of posts to the [...]

Tags: excerpt

Is there an easy method of adding the last few words of the posts, added to the trimmed excerpt that is automatically generated for post displayed on category pages?

Currently it will only show the first given number of words, and I would like it to have the first few words and the last few words, something like following

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 [...] 997 998 999 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the_excerpt filter. You can read further on the codex. Just  paste this code in functions.php and set the value of $i = no of words from the end you want.

```
add_filter('the_excerpt','my_excerpt');
function my_excerpt(){
    global $post;                         
    $excerpt=get_the_excerpt();
    $content = get_the_content(); //gets the whole content
    $content =strip_tags($content) ; //strips html tags                  
    $content = explode(" ", $content); //stores each word in an array
    $size = count($content);        //counts the length of array                                
    $last="";                       //initialize an empty sting
    $i=4;                           //no of words from the last you want
    while($i>0){
        $last.= $content[$size-$i];   
        $last.=" ";
        $i--;  
    }  
    return $excerpt."......".$last;
}
```

Now use  `the_excerpt();` to output the kind excerpt you want. 
All the best and let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: this is great however it also outputs the code and html tags and image tags as the end string and not only the actual text of the last words, I would like for it to display the last few words of the formatted content

Comment: Use `wp_strip_all_tags()` or `wp_filter_nohtml_kses()` on the content returned by `get_the_content()` to get rid of the tags. @webestdesigns

Comment: @ialocin Thanks I used `$content = wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_content());`

Answer (score 1):

You can wordpress excerpt using maximam **character** OR **word** count and display like

> Loriem ipsum[...]

so I have solution.

This code put in **function.php**

```
/** 
 *  The Excerpt for word counting in the_content or excerpt.
 */  
function getCharCut($text, $limit)
{
    $char_cut=substr(strip_tags(stripslashes($text)),0,$limit);
    if(strlen($text)<=$limit) 
    return  $char_cut; 
    else
    return esc_html($char_cut." [...]");    
}
```

You can use the **excerpt** or **content** count character OR word .

```
    <?php
        if(get_the_excerpt())
        {
            $mycontent = get_the_excerpt();
            echo getCharCut($mycontent, 105);
        }           
    ?>
```

Comment: Please do not tag answers

Comment: Thanks but I would like to cut the middle, and to display both the beginning of the post content and the end of the post content. How would I be able to display the last few words as well as the first few words? not to just count the x number of words from the beginning to display.

Comment: I am useing Tag because tag to search and display answer in strackoverflow. Like, wordpress is a Tag to search people and get Result .